# Why doesn't WinEdt 8.0 produce PDF output?

Tags: pdf, winedt

I am using WinEdt in Windows 7. A problem occurs when I am trying to compile a LaTeX file with PDFLaTeX. After compilation it does not produce any PDF file and even existing PDF files are deleted.

Before compiling the LaTeX file, I have

[image]

After compilation I get

[image]

After compilation the icon “View PDF” becomes inactive. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Note that no `.pdf` file has been generated by the compilation, as you can see in the compilation report (Pages: 0). That's why the "PDF Viewer" button is grayed out.

Comment: I have not had any such problems but I also update my TeX distribution often (MikTeX). Otherwise WindEdt should simply use the paths defined by the installation to find the appropriate software and likewise for the viewer.

Comment: With no MWE this is unclear